# Why is de-referencing the pointer and printing the value crashing the program

Tags: c, pointers

The following program gives the result correctly

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int address = 0x00018EA0;
    int *flashLocat = (int*)address;
    printf("%x\n%x\n%x\n",address,flashLocat,&flashLocat);

    return 0;
}
```

output

```
    18ea0
    18ea0
    180209e0
```

Whereas the above program in the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int address = 0x00018EA0;
    int *flashLocat = (int*)address;
    printf("%x\n%x\n%x\n%x\n",address,*flashLocat,flashLocat,&flashLocat);

    return 0;
}
```

is crashing, why is it crashing? It would be great if someone answers. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you think that the address `0x00018EA0` is valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you don't know if the address `0x00018EA0` is valid or not.

In the first program, you are not accessing the memory location `0x00018EA0`, you are just accessing the address and the address of the pointer.

```
printf("%x\n%x\n%x\n",address,flashLocat,&flashLocat);

// address  --> is value of pointer, so it is valid
// flashLocat --> is value of pointer, so it is valid
// &flashLocat--> is the address of flashLocat, so it is valid
```

But in the second program, you are actually accessing the memory location, which gives you error, if the address is invalid.

```
printf("%x\n%x\n%x\n%x\n",address,*flashLocat,flashLocat,&flashLocat);

// *flashLocat --> trying to access the location, can be INVALID
```

Answer (score 2):

`0x00018EA0` is a random address that (as far as anyone can tell) has no significance. The chance that it is mapped to a page at all is miniscule; the chance that it is mapped to a page that your userspace process has permissions for even more so.

As a result, when you *dereference* the pointer -- access that memory that may not exist and that you likely don't have permission to access -- you get an error, specifically a segmentation fault.

The first program doesn't crash because it never accesses the memory -- it only looks at the value of a pointer that is never accessed.